# Jenkins git plugin on windows 2003 server

Tags: windows, git, jenkins

I cant seem to get the git plugin working on Jenkins. Have searched and tried every possible suggested solution.

I have setup Git, Putty plink, environment variables, ssh keys correctly.

Git from the command line or Git Bash works fine. I can run all the commands that Jenkins is attempting to run and have no issues.

I have a copy of .ssh folder to both c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator and C:\Program Files\Git.

The Jenkins windows service is running at the Administrator acccount, as apposed to the Local System.

When Jenkins kicks off a build i keep getting the error :  No supported authentication methods available. This to appears like Jenkins is not able to find the keys in the .ssh folder.

Hope someone can help.

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\websites\companya\ci\ci1build
Checkout:ci1build / C:\websites\companya\ci\ci1build - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1b2bb77
Using strategy: Default
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:companya/companya.git
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe fetch -t git@github.com:companya/companya.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '-t' 'git@github.com:companya/companya.git' '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
trace: run_command: 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe' '-batch' 'git@github.com' 'git-upload-pack '\''companya/companya.git'\'''
FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:818)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommand(GitAPI.java:780)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.fetch(GitAPI.java:196)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.fetch(GitAPI.java:1026)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:812)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.access$100(GitSCM.java:90)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1096)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1064)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:842)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:824)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1064)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1245)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:589)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:494)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1488)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1103)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1064)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:842)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:824)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1064)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1245)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:589)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:494)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1488)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running Jenkins from the console, instead of as a service.

Comment: Don't think you can run it from command line in Windows. Throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find your private key (maybe you are running as different user?).

According to the Git plugin doc, you can [the home enviromnetal variable](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Setupyourenvironmentvariables):

> HOME => Folder where your SSH Keys are located (e.g C:\SSHKeys)

Comment: Tried to setup all the ENV settings in Jenkins but still no luck.